# Shortcode parse error - wrong syntax

Tags: functions, shortcode

I am trying to combine html and running a shortcode in my custom function output but I am getting a parse error. Please see below for what I am trying to achieve. Is this approach correct or is there a better way of achieving this?

```
   function gshar_text_shortcode() {
        return '<span class="kalia">Share with friends</span><div class="kalisha">' . echo do_shortcode('[share facebook="true" twitter="true" linkedin="true" email="true"]') . '</div>';
    }
    add_shortcode('globeshare', 'gshar_text_shortcode');
```

My `[share]` shortcode in functions.php

```
  function x_portfolio_item_social_v2() {

    $share_project_title = x_get_option( 'x_portfolio_share_project_title' );
      $enable_facebook     = x_get_option( 'x_portfolio_enable_facebook_sharing' );
      $enable_twitter      = x_get_option( 'x_portfolio_enable_twitter_sharing' );
      $enable_google_plus  = x_get_option( 'x_portfolio_enable_google_plus_sharing' );
      $enable_linkedin     = x_get_option( 'x_portfolio_enable_linkedin_sharing' );
      $enable_pinterest    = x_get_option( 'x_portfolio_enable_pinterest_sharing' );
      $enable_reddit       = x_get_option( 'x_portfolio_enable_reddit_sharing' );
      $enable_email        = x_get_option( 'x_portfolio_enable_email_sharing' );

      $share_url     = urlencode( get_permalink() );
      $share_title   = urlencode( get_the_title() );
      $share_source  = urlencode( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) );
      $share_content = urlencode( get_the_excerpt() );
      $share_image   = urlencode( x_get_featured_image_with_fallback_url() );

     [truncated...]

      if ( $enable_facebook == '1' || $enable_twitter == '1' || $enable_google_plus == '1' || $enable_linkedin == '1' || $enable_pinterest == '1' || $enable_reddit == '1' || $enable_email == '1' ) :

        ?>

        <div class="x-entry-share">
          <div class="x-share-options">
            <?php echo $facebook . $twitter . $google_plus . $linkedin . $pinterest . $reddit . urldecode( $email ); ?>
          </div>
        </div>

      <?php

    endif;

  }

add_action('wp_head', 'change_item_social_v2');

function change_item_social_v2() {
    remove_shortcode( 'share' );
    add_shortcode( 'share', 'x_portfolio_item_social_v2' );
  }
```

Comment: what is the exact full text of the parse error?

Comment: Michael, we have fixed the parse error, but now we are trying to figure out, why my functions.php [share] shortcode outputs at the top of the page whereas if I don't use it in my functions.php, it works fine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### UPDATE

Seems like the shortcode you're trying to use is not well coded. If they use it somewhere in the templates alone like `echo do_shortcode('[share]');` it doesn't really matter since the `'[share]'` is the only content passed to `do_shortcode()`. In your case you're trying to reuse the shortcode in a context where it's placed among other content - that's what the shortcodes are for in the first place. Try for following code:

```
add_action('wp_head', function() {

  // bail if shortcode doesn't exists
  if ( ! shortcode_exists( 'share' ) ) {
    return;
  }

  remove_shortcode( 'share' ); // remove what is defined before in change_item_social_v2()

  add_shortcode( 'share', function( $args = [], $content = '' ) {
    ob_start();

    x_portfolio_item_social_v2( $args, $content );

    return ob_get_clean();
  } );
}, 100 ); // high hook order 100 > 10 (default), ensure this is called after original change_item_social_v2()
```

By calling `ob_start()` before `x_portfolio_item_social_v2()` we are simply preventing whatever is output, since that moment, to "display", instead we store it into a buffer which is flushed and its contents returned by `ob_get_clean()`, acting like a proper shortcode handler.

#### ORIGINAL

I don't see a parse issue here but the obvious mistake is echoing in a function that should return. You see your `echo do_shortcode(...)` is actually echoing immediately at that time it's run. `echo` will output but will not have a return and it will never be where you expect it to be (inside `<div class="kalis"></div>`). First try removing `echo`

Comment: ok I removed echo and it works but the output of [share] shortcode is displayed on top of the page, instead of being where I call it from.. I can post the full code of [share] shortcode if needed.

Comment: I would expect the output of `[share]` to be on top when `echo` **IS there.

Comment: yes there is an echo, but the theme uses this function and it shows up correctly. It's only when I modify the function in my functions.php in child theme that it shows on top. Please see updated question with [share] code.

Comment: Are you sure `x_portfolio_item_social_v2` function is passed as second argument in `add_shortcode( 'share', 'x_portfolio_item_social_v2' )` ? It doesn't look like a proper shortcode handler since it doesn't return.

Comment: yes, its passed - i forgot part of the code which i have now added at the bottom.

Comment: That `[share]` shortcode is broken in the first place. See my updated answer.

Comment: ok this makes sense now, and everything works as expected using your answer - many thanks Zlatev xxx